# Cannot use smart Vue3 UI component in Nuxt3 with SSR

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, server-side-rendering

I am trying to make a smart design system that provides 'widgets', little UI components with their own instance of axios and fetching their own data for display.

I created a simple Vite library with a component that fetches some pokemon information. I built it and shared it locally via yalc. When I tried to import it locally in my Nuxt app. It works only with no-ssr tags and when I try to load it with SSR I get the following error: [image]

How can I make my axios call inside the UI component compatible wih Nuxt SSR ?

The Nuxt3 app is a classic fresh sample using the CLI, and the UI component is a basic Vue3 app in library mode using Vite.

UI component:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios'

let {data: data2} = await axios
.get("https://api-pokemon-fr.vercel.app/api/v1/pokemon/badabouin")
</script>

<template>
  <div class="ui-first-card">
      <p :style="{ color: 'cyan' }">pokemon</p>
    <p :style="{ color: 'cyan' }">{{ data2.sprites.regular}}</p>
    <img :src="data2.sprites.regular" alt="pokemonImg">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Try to use the built-in `$fetch` maybe.

Comment: Yes I first tried with native fetch first to use least dependencies possible but it fails all the same

Comment: This one? https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/dollarfetch#fetch

Comment: No, but my library is in vue3 so it does not have access to Nuxt useFetch